# Тормоза при работе с DataGridView

Tags: c#, база-данных

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело. При потере фокуса данные в ячейке появляются спустя примерно полсекунды, не меньше, в общем очень медленно. По обработчику кнопки если выполнить код, то так же себя ведет.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuild;
        private System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;
        private System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn;
        private System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd;
        private System.Data.DataView dv;
        private System.Data.DataTable dt;
        private string connStr;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"data source=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\baza.mdb";
                conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
                cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from students";
                dt = new DataTable();
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();

                dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.AllowDelete = false;
                dv.AllowEdit = true;
                dv.AllowNew = false;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdBuild = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
                da.UpdateCommand = cmdBuild.GetUpdateCommand();
                conn.Open();
                da.Update(dt);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdBuild = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
                da.UpdateCommand = cmdBuild.GetUpdateCommand();
                conn.Open();
                da.Update(dt);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдено решение, надеюсь правильное. Вынести обработку события в отдельный поток. Например:

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
          try
          {
              cmdBuild = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
              da.UpdateCommand = cmdBuild.GetUpdateCommand();
              conn.Open();
              da.Update(dt);
              conn.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
          }
      });
    }
```